# Как правильно организовать характеристики товаров на MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы:

**Category**

`id | name | description`

и

**Product**

`id | category_id | name | description`

Появилась необходимость через админку добавлять/редактировать/удалять кастомные атрибуты категориям, и так же - через админку - значения атрибутов товаров. Например, есть следующие категории: `Продукты питания`, `Техника`. Нужно `Продуктам питания` добавить атрибут `Энергетическая ценность`, а `Технике` - `Потребляемая мощность`.

1-й вопрос: как правильно организовать данные?

2-й вопрос: каким запросом, можно будет выбрать всю `Технику` с `Потребляемой мощностью` от 100 до 200 Вт?

3-й вопрос: каким запросом можно будет редактировать/удалить ненужный атрибут

Comment: Использовать связи. Отдельная таблица с атрибутами, их названиями и т.д. Отдельная таблица с id товара и id атрибута. Можно конечно обойти промежуточную таблицу, вписав массив id атрибутов прямо в товар, но данный вариант прям не комильфо.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно больше таблиц. Как минимум, еще две: таблица определений атрибутов (имя, заголовок, тип), записи которой по ключу привязаны к категориям, и таблица значений атрибутов, записи которой привязаны двумя ключами - к записям в таблице определений и к записям в таблице продуктов. На это все нужны продуманные индексы.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Answer (score 0):

Єсли атрибути будут добавлятса с админки и их количество не определено (но вероятно очень много) то я б рекомендовал реализовать структура подобную как в Magento
больше про структура можна почитать здесь [здесь](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-eav-database-structure/) или [здесь](https://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/MAGENTO_v1.3.2.4-Database_Diagram.pdf)